# Select pandas dataframe column that has NaN or NULL values and fill it with 0's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has some missing data in a few different columns. How do I write a function that identifies the columns with missing (i.e. NaN or NULL values) data and fills them with 0's?

I currently have this for inputting specific columns where I already know there is missing data; however I'm trying to come up with a function that finds columns with missing data on its own.

```
def fill_blanks(dataframe, column):
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Where is your data? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Did you have a look at [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)? It can fill all Null/NaN values in all columns at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fillna(0)` on entire dataframe:

```
dataframe = dataframe.fillna(0)
```

or:

```
dataframe.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why create a function that does the same thing as another function?

Comment: Because he has a function in his code. In this specific example it's not really necessary, I agree.

Comment: Yeah its just a bit superfluous. People learning will come here and might think they have to define a function to do this, when a function already exists without the need to adjust it.

Answer (score 3):

you can just use `.fillna()`

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

or

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

Comment: two ways to do the same thing